# Masive Update on Column Descriptions of SQL Server from Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Where I work there are some data-dictionary of the databases created in Excel files with the following format:

```
 Database|Instance  |Table    |Column   |Description  
 BD1     |dbo       |Table1   |Column1  |DescriptionA
 BD1     |dbo       |Table1   |Column2  |DescriptionB
 BD1     |dbo       |Table1   |Column3  |DescriptionC
 BD2     |dbo       |Table1   |Column1  |DescriptionD
```

I need to do an update to the description of the columns. I know I can do it with SSMS column by column, but that's a lot of work.
As far as I know, I must update the following table: sys.extended_properties

¿Is there a tool or some way to do a masive update like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the spreadsheet to a SQL Server table.
Write a cursor to loop through the table, adding each property using:

```
   Declare   @sql as nvarchar(max)
            , @Database as nvarchar(max)
            , @Instance as nvarchar(100)
            , @Table as nvarchar(100)
            , @Column as nvarchar(100)
            , @Description as nvarchar(100)

    Declare mycursor cursor for Select [Database], [Instance], [Table], [Column], [Description] from MyImportedTable
    open mycursor
    fetch next from mycursor into @Database, @Instance, @Table, @Column, @Description
    while @@FETCH_STATUS= 0
        begin
        set @sql = 'EXEC [' + @Database + '].[' @Schema + '].sp_addextendedproperty   
                    @name = N''Description'',   
                    @value = ''' + @Description + ''',  
                    @level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = ' + @Instance + ',  
                    @level1type = N''Table'',  @level1name = ' + @Table + ',  
                    @level2type = N''Column'', @level2name = ' + @Column + ';'
        EXEC (@sql)
        fetch next from mycursor into @Database, @Instance, @Table, @Column, @Description
        END
    close mycursor
    deallocate mycursor
```